# ¿Como guardar en sessionstorage un alerta con sweetalert?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

Estoy intentando que cuando se abra una pagina web aparezca al principio una alerta, con alert("") funciona correctamente y se guarda pero quiero poner sweetalert pero no me aparece el popup ni se guarda en la sessionstorage

He probado de esta manera:

```
   if (sessionStorage.getItem('intro')!= 'false'){ 
                Swal.fire("Esta es una alerta");
                sessionStorage.setItem('intro','false');}
```

Y de esta:

```
 if (sessionStorage.getItem('intro')!= 'false'){ 
                swal({
                    title: 'Titulo',
                    text: 'Mensaje de texto',
                    window.alert("Esto es una alerta")
                });
                sessionStorage.setItem('intro','false');}
```

Pero no aparece el mensaje, si alguien me pudiera ayudar.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Que significa "nada"? Aparece el mensaje? No aparece? Por favor intenta aclarar lo que sucede. Saludos

Comment: No aparece el mensaje al entrar en la web, y tampoco se guarda en sessionstorage

Comment: verificaste la consola a ver si existe algun error?

Answer (score -1):

Vale estuve revisando la consola y decidi este metodo mas adecuado:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem('intro')!= 'false'){ 
            swal({
                title: 'Titulo',
                text: 'Mensaje de texto',
                html:'Esto es una alerta',
            });
            sessionStorage.setItem('intro','false');}
```

gracias por todo.

Comment: No entiendo que eso solucione el problema que decias tener con el sweetalert, pues no has cambiado nada... ¿quizás no tenias cargada la librería de sweetalert2 y de ahí que no te funcionara antes?

Comment: lo que quite fue window.alert(); me fallaba eso, al meter la informacion en el html no me dio error.

Comment: perdón, tienes razón, eso sobraba, no he comparado bien la pregunta y la respuesta, fallo mio.